# Flutter - Custom Timer avoid moving numbers?

Tags: flutter, timer, flutter-layout, countdowntimer, flutter-animation

I'm struggling to fix the following issue shown in the gif. I'm using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_timer) package for the timer. And I can't figure it out how to avoid the moving of the countdown timer while counting down. It’s moving because of different widths of each number.

**Gif:**

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/TeaxDNgqUDaA5whn8W)

**Code:**

```
Consumer<RunSettingsModel>(
            builder: (context, settings, _) => CustomTimer(
              from: Duration(seconds: settings.runDuration),
              to: Duration(seconds: 0),
              controller: _runController,
              builder: (CustomTimerRemainingTime remaining) {
                final double percent = 1 -
                    remaining.duration.inSeconds.toDouble() /
                        settings.runDuration;
                settings.remainingTime = remaining.duration.inSeconds;
                return  Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          "${remaining.hours}:${remaining.minutes}:${remaining.seconds}",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: So what's wrong with that? It is supposed to be like that due to a change in the width of characters as you already know.

Comment: I dont want the first character to mvoe

Answer (score 6):

you can import 'dart:ui';

and then in your Text Widget use a TextStyle of
`fontFeatures: [FontFeature.tabularFigures()]`,

like so:

```
Text("${remaining.hours}:${remaining.minutes}:${remaining.seconds}",
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontFeatures: [FontFeature.tabularFigures()]),
 );
```

Comment: it basically solves the problem but then digits are randomly flicking ! IDK why

Answer (score 1):

You should try to separate each digit(hours, minutes and seconds) in its own `Text` widget and wrap them with a `Container` to keep them always at the center. I am creating a new widget for the digits because most of the widgets used would repeat themselves.

```
class DigitsContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const DigitsContainer(
    this.text, {
    required this.style,
  });

  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("", style: style),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your main widget.

```
...
return Column(children: [
            DigitsContainer(remaining.hours.toString(), style: style),
            Text(":", style: style),
            DigitsContainer(remaining.minutes.toString(), style: style),
            Text(":", style: style),
            DigitsContainer(remaining.minutes.toString(), style: style),
          ]),
...
```

Also make sure to wrap this `Column` in a `Container` with fixed with so that you dont have problem with the `Expanded` widget inside the `DigitsContainer` one. I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `Container` wrapping your `Text` as shown in the [custom_timer](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_timer) package.
As you can see, in the package example there is no `Container`, the `Container` might be changing it's size because it doesn't have a fixed width and height.
This is the package simple example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("CustomTimer example"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CustomTimer(
            from: Duration(hours: 12),
            to: Duration(hours: 0),
            onBuildAction: CustomTimerAction.auto_start,
            builder: (CustomTimerRemainingTime remaining) {
              return Text(
                "${remaining.hours}:${remaining.minutes}:${remaining.seconds}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```